# R/R Studio and Sleep Mode

Tags: r

I am running some JAGS code in R Studio. I started it before I went to bed knowing it would take a few hours to finish. I forgot to turn off the sleep mode, and the computer (Windows 10) went to sleep after 2 hours. I woke up this morning and saw that only 60% of the model had run with 40% left to go. A few minutes later after I had made coffee, I noticed that the model had resumed and was now at 63% done.

Will my results be OK or should I discard them and start new? I am not sure how R and R Studio react when a computer goes to sleep.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be fine---as far as I understand, it has just paused sampling during the night, which shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Thank you, that makes me feel better. I'll be sure to make sure the computer doesn't sleep in the future.

Comment: If/Once the run finishes, you will inspect the posterior distributions anyway. Anything weird should probably stand out.